# How do I set up security on Sql Server to allow access by a WCF service?

Tags: sql-server, wcf

I have a WCF service hosted within IIS that logs information in a sql server 2008 db. I have successfully tested this within my local IIS and SS2008 db (using an application pool running under my windows id).

Now I have moved the database and wcf service to the production server and wondering how to set the security up on the database to allow access by the WCF service (presumably running under a local IIS account / default application pool).

The IIS server and the db server are on different machines (in the same domain).
The database is using integrated authentication.

Comment: Sounds like a question for http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Set up domain identity impersonation for the IIS pool, and give that identity access to the relevant Database.

Or give the local IIS account access to the relevant Database.